# React Firebase Hosting deploys blank page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a problem with React App. I am trying to deploy it.

```
npm run build
```

then I use `firebase init` and I show the build folder as the one which is supposed to be deployed. Then I `firebase deploy` and it shows a blank page.

My app url: https://tutorm-db33prg.firebaseapp.com

Would you be so kind to help me? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: when I check the debug console it shows:

```
main.66af2304.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: i.a.initializeApp is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at t (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at t (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at t (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at t (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.66af2304.js:1)
    at t (main.66af2304.js:1)
```

Comment: Check the debug console !

Comment: @formatkaka I checked it. Please check the updated post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's `firebase-tools` that causes the error. What I did, I created another app with `create-react-app` and simply copied the content of my `public` and `src` folders without installing any dependencies regarding firebase.

It worked well and I deployed it to Netlify which was super simple and easy to do!